MongoDB - move null values when sorting to the end
MongoDB treats null as the smallest value, so if I have 3 documents like this:
{
    "total": 1000,
    "page": 1,
    "limit": 100,
    "totalPages": 33,
    "listings": [
        {
            "_id": "6765863a77f40a7d8ff15098",
            "attr": 1
        },
        {
            "_id": "6765810777f40a7d8ff15088",
            "attr": 2
        },
        {
            "_id": "67657fae77f40a7d8ff15076",
            "attr": null
        }
    ]
}

Default mongo asc sorting shows third one (with attr: null) as the smallest one.
This is my endpoint and piece of its implementation in Node.js, Express:
/listings?page=0&limit=100&sort=asc&sortBy=attr
    const sort = {};
    if (req.query.sortBy) {
      const sortOrder = req.query.sort === "desc" ? -1 : 1;
      sort[req.query.sortBy] = sortOrder;
    } else {
      sort.dataUtworzenia = -1;
    }

    const total = await Listing.countDocuments(query);
    const listings = await Listing.find(query)
      .sort(sort)
      .skip(skip)
      .limit(limit);

Is it possible to sort the attributes in such a way that the non-null ones are sorted first, and the null ones are thrown at the end?
Important: All my documents contain the full amount of necessary attributes, if an attribute has no value it is null but present in the document
I tried aggregation but it was hard to connect it with my node.js express code.

Set an order key, for example like this:
db.Listing.aggregate([
   { $match: query },
   { $set: { orderKey: { $ifNnull: [`$${req.query.sortBy}`, { "$maxKey" : 1 }] } } },
   { $sort: { orderKey: req.query.sort === "desc" ? -1 : 1 } },
   { $unset: "orderKey" },
   { $skip: skip },
   { $limit: limit }
])

Maybe internal type MaxKey / { "$maxKey" : 1 } does not work. In this case use a value/data type from Ascending/Descending Sort which is greater than the greatest value you expect in your data.
